# Use Windows Laptop as Monitor via HDMI Cable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hdmi

I have a laptop running Windows 10 Home, and want to use it as a display monitor for my Raspberry Pi, via a HDMI cable.

Basically, I want to treat the HDMI entry in my laptop as an **input**, not as an **output**.

After searching online for this for Windows 10, I was only able to find [guides on doing it for wireless displays](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-your-laptop-second-monitor), not for using an HDMI cable.

Is this possible to do with just Windows 10? Or is third-party software neccessary?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/change-hdmi-output-input-laptop/ (basically, you need an HDMI capture-card. Software alone cannot)

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question for StackOverflow, as it is not directly related to coding. Please check out [the list of alternative sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) available